# Microsoft.VisualBasic.Powerpacks.ShapeContainer not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am developing a game in C# and it works properly here in my laptop. But when I tried to run it in other pc's its getting an error **"Microsoft.VisualBasic.Powerpacks.ShapeContainer could not be found".** I used Visual Studio 2008 and the pc's I have tried running also uses Visual Studio 2008.

Does anyone knows how to solve this error?

Will removing the lines, panels I have used in the forms helps?

Answer (score 5):

You should download and install [Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=25169).

Comment: Exact same issue I am facing with someone else's source code. I've got the power packs too.

Comment: even if i downloaded the power pack, it was causing problem. according to this thread .. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/39373637-da19-42a4-80e8-24e9e1f10190/what-happened?forum=csharpgeneral , I dragged a line shape from power pack of toolbox, then rebuild the project, it ran without any issue.

Comment: for me the form didn't open, adding reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks` solved the issue